# i want to get data through fromDate & toDate on employe code

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

here is my stored procedure...this stored procedure showing result for fromdate and toate on employee code,an aggregate function for differentiate checkIn and checkout...
it shows data for checkout time only for one date,the problem is ,I need this for multiple days...

If any one know what is the problem kindly share your experience with me, and point my mistakes in query...
I shall be thankful

here is the tables script

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ras_AttRecord](
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [DN] [smallint] NULL,
        [DIN] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [Clock] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        [VerifyMode] [tinyint] NULL,
        [AttTypeId] [char](3) NOT NULL,
        [CollectDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        [LastUpdatedUID] [int] NULL,
        [LastUpdatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [Remark] [nvarchar](64) NULL
        )

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ras_Users](
        [UID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [DIN] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [PIN] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
        [UserName] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
        [Sex] [char](1) NOT NULL,
        [Password] [nvarchar](32) NULL,
        [PasswordQuestion] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
        [PasswordAnswer] [nvarchar](32) NULL,
        [IsApproved] [bit] NOT NULL,
        [IsLockedOut] [bit] NOT NULL,
        [CreateDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [LastLoginDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [DeptId] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
        [AttId] [char](4) NULL,
        [RuleId] [char](4) NULL,
        [WeekendId] [char](4) NULL,
        [LastUpdatedUID] [int] NULL,
        [LastUpdatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        [Comment] [nvarchar](128) NULL
        )
```

I'm using this stored procedure

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLateComersmonthly]       
    @FromDate DATE='05/22/2017', 
    @ToDate DATE='06/06/2017',       
    @Code varchar(6)  ='3155'      
AS       
BEGIN        
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from        
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.        
    SET NOCOUNT ON;       
    IF  @Code = '0'        
    SET @Code = null      

    -- Insert statements for procedure here        
    select 
        T1.UserName, 
        T1.DIN as [DIN], 
        min(T1.Date) as [Date], 
        min(T1.Time) as [Time], 
        CASE   
            WHEN max(T2.Time) = max(T1.Time) THEN '' 
            ELSE max(T2.Time)  end as [Timee], min(T1.Day) as [Day],
        CASE   
            WHEN concat(CONVERT(varchar,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,min(T1.Time),max(t2.Time)),108)/60,
                         ':', 
                        CONVERT(varchar,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,min(T1.Time),max(t2.Time))%60,108)) = '0:0' 
            THEN 'No Check Out' 
            ELSE concat(CONVERT(varchar,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,min(T1.Time),max(t2.Time)),108)/60, 
                        ':',
                        CONVERT(varchar,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,min(T1.Time),max(t2.Time))%60,108)) 
            END AS hrs
    from 
        (SELECT 
            UserName , 
            ru.DIN, 
            CONVERT(varchar, Att.Clock, 101) AS Date, 
            CONVERT(varchar, Att.Clock, 108) AS Time, 
            att.VerifyMode as Mode, DATENAME(dw, Att.Clock) AS Day        
        FROM 
            ras_Users as ru        
            inner join ras_AttRecord as att ON ru.DIN = att.Din        
        where  CONVERT(DATE,Clock) >= @FromDate 
                and CONVERT(DATE,Clock)<=@ToDate 
                and att.DIN = COALESCE (@Code,  att.DIN) 
                and att.VerifyMode = 15   
        ) as T1 
        left join 
        (SELECT  
            ru.DIN, 
            max(CONVERT(varchar, Att.Clock, 108)) AS Time  
         FROM 
            ras_Users as ru        
            inner join ras_AttRecord as att ON ru.DIN = att.Din        
         where  CONVERT(DATE,Clock) >= @FromDate 
                and  CONVERT(DATE,Clock)<=@ToDate 
                and att.DIN = COALESCE (@Code,  att.din) 
         group by ru.DIN, att.Clock 
        ) as  T2  on T1.DIN = T2.DIN --and DATEDIFF(MINUTE,T1.Time,t2.Time)/60 < 9
    group by 
        T1.Username, 
        T1.din,
        T1.Day      
    -- having CONVERT(varchar, min(T1.Time), 108) > '09:30:00'   
    order by T1.din

END
```

its shows the following result

Current Record displaying

```
Userid  Date            CheckIn         CheckOut    Day       total hours
    3155    05/26/2017  09:15:10    17:15:00  Friday      8:0
    3155    05/29/2017  09:08:36    17:15:00  Monday      8:7
    3155    05/25/2017  09:34:28    17:15:00  Thursday        7:41
    3155    05/30/2017  09:15:12    17:15:00  Tuesday     8:0
    3155    05/31/2017  09:27:37    17:15:00  Wednesday       7:48
```

and I need the following result 
Expected Result

```
  Userid      Date        CheckIn         CheckOut         day  total hours
3155    05/26/2017  09:15:10    17:00:00    Friday    8:0
3155    05/29/2017  09:08:36    17:05:00    Monday    8:7
3155    05/25/2017  09:34:28    17:30:00    Thursday  7:41
3155    05/30/2017  09:15:12    17:18:00    Tuesday   8:0
3155    05/31/2017  09:27:37    17:10:00    Wednesday 7:48
```

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/xQbxCWqVf5

Comment: this is the current result

Comment: I think you should post some sample data (as text ), so we can try to help you.

Comment: in the first comment I have shared the actual result as 
over here
https://www.screencast.com/t/xQbxCWqVf5

Comment: Sample of source data.  And please avoid images (use only formatted text--> see introductory stackoverflow tour)

Comment: @AhsanAsim Please provide table script for these 2 tables ras_Users , 
ras_AttRecord . Also Provide insert queries for adding records in these tables..

Comment: table 1 
ras_Users
UID,DIN,PIN,USerName,Sex,Password,PasswordQuestion,PasswordAnswer,IsApproved,IsLockedOut,CreateDate,LastLoginDate,
DeptId,AttId,RuleId,WeekendId,LastUpdatedUID,LastUpdatedDate,Comment
table 2
ras_AttRecord
ID,DN,DIN,Clock,VerifyMode,AttTypeId,CollectDate,LastUpdatedUID,LastUpdatedDate,Remark

Comment: Pls think: how can someone reproduce your problem?  What would you need if someone asked you a similar question (eg. script to create tables, script for insert, etc.)?   Then pls post all you expected to have in that case, in a clear format (text added to the question, not in comment)

Comment: @Ahsan Asim  You should post insert scripts for the two tables (=input data), so I can reproduce your output.

Comment: Column names in the procedure and expected result not same. Could you fix?